# Apache CXF Validation Bean with @RequestBody consuming JSON

Tags: json, spring, validation, cxf, javabeans

I have spent all my day searching how can i validate my bean passed with @RequestBody (JSON). We are using Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE and CXF 2.7.7, but i found only examples using @Controller and @RequestMapping, that i can't use because we use @Path annotation.

This my Ressource to validate :

```
@Path("/clients")
@Service("com.company.services.client.rsl.si.ClientServiceRest")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class ClientServiceRestImpl implements ClientServiceRest {
......
@Override
@POST
public Response saveClient(@Valid @RequestBody ClientDto clientDto, BindingResult result) {

    Client clientSaved = clientService.saveClient(clientDto);
    if (clientEnregistre == null || result.hasErrors()) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(result.getAllErrors()).build();
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    } else {
        return Response.ok(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
    }

}
```

And ClientDto :

```
@Data
public class ClientDto {

    private Long idClient;

    @NotNull(message = "Le code client est obligatoire !")
    private String codeClient;
    @NotNull(message = "Le nom client est obligatoire !")
    private String nomClient;
    ....
    }
```

I always have the BindingResult null, i have surely believe something to configure.

Another complexity, is that we need to validate all the Dto in one request.

I'have surely believe something to configure.
Thank you so much.

Comment: That is never going to work. `@Valid`, `@RequestBody` and `BindingResult` are classes belonging to Spring MVC those are never going to work in a JAX-RS class. For those to work they need to be in a `@Controller` and not a JAX-RS based class.

Comment: That's right.. i'm trying validate my beans with cxf interceptors